# How to catch every fatal error in a Hapi NodeJS app, and send a 500 error to clients?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

Given a NodeJS app serving an API via Hapi, how do I catch all errors so they can be communicated to the user? I need to be able to send a 500 error to any client that has made a request to our server, when a fatal error occurs.

We thought we had already set everything up to correctly catch all errors, but this one got past us entirely.

I did "git clone" to get the app from Github, then "npm install" and then "npm run". Then I worked with the app for a few hours. Then I closed up my laptop and went home. Hours later I opened the laptop and I wanted to continue working. But the connection to the external database had gone stale. That certainly makes sense, but our app should have communicated a problem to the client. Instead, when I ran cURL:

```
  curl "http://nefers-mbp.home:3000/profile/Company/31468" -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'x-api-key: 2gt7Pt2LU194KKcNnXHRc564JU'
```

After 90 seconds it hit the default cURL timeout:

```
  curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

This is not acceptable for us. I want an error to be sent instantly.

In the terminal window where I was running the app, I saw that the database connection had gone stale, which lead to an error:

```
  160920/111554.302, [ops], memory: 49Mb, uptime (seconds): 24285.523, load: 1.6513671875,2.2822265625,3.7041015625
  { profile_type: 'Company', id: '31468' }
  { method: 'select',
    options: {},
    bindings: [ '2gt7Pt2LU194KKcNUxJU' ],
    sql: 'select `user_id`, `action`, `permission` from `api_permissions` where `api_key` = ?' }
  160920/11124.308, [ops], memory: 49Mb, uptime (seconds): 24315.529, load: 1.55640625,2.204105625,3.6259765625
  Knex:Error Pool2 - Error: Pool.release(): Resource not member of pool
  { Error: read ETIMEDOUT
      at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
      at TCP.onread (net.js:564:26)
      --------------------
      at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/lsam/projects/mattermare/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
      at Connection.query (/Users/lsam/projects/mattermare/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:201:25)
      at /Users/lsam/projects/mattermare/api/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:92:18
      at tryCatcher (/Users/lsam/projects/mattermare/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
      at Promise._resolveFromResolver (/Users/lsam/projects/mattermare/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:483:31)
      at new Promise (/Users/lsam/projects/mattermare/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:71:37)
      at Client._query (/Users/lsam/projects/mattermare/api/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:88:12)
      at Client.query (/Users/lsam/projects/mattermare/api/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:127:24)
      at Runner.<anonymous> (/Users/lsam/projects/mattermare/api/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:116:24)
      at Runner.tryCatcher (/Users/lsam/projects/mattermare/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
      at Runner.query (/Users/lsam/projects/mattermare/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/method.js:15:34)
      at /Users/lsam/projects/mattermare/api/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:44:21
      at /Users/lsam/projects/mattermare/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/using.js:176:30
      at bound (domain.js:280:14)
      at runBound (domain.js:293:12)
      at tryCatcher (/Users/lsam/projects/mattermare/api/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    syscall: 'read',
    fatal: true }
```

This error, in the console, was instant, but it was not communicated to the waiting cURL request. This is what I want to fix.

I went looking for npm packages that would help, and I found this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-error

but apparently, that only makes error messages pretty. Our problem is more fundamental: we failed to catch this fatal error.

The server automatically fixed itself so the next time I called cURL it had an active database connection, and so the next call worked great.

But we need to catch every single error, no matter the reason, and make sure the client gets a reasonable message. We can not allow a situation where clients are left to simply timeout.

I do get that if I had Apache or Nginx in front of this, via reverse proxy, then they could timeout faster, but as a matter of correctness, we want the NodeJS app to itself send an error message when an error has occurred.

We already use "good" which catches most errors:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/good

Which we register as:

```
  {
      "plugin": {
      "register": "good",
        "options": {
            "opsInterval": 30000,
            "reporters": [
            {
                "reporter": "good-console",
                "events": {
                    "log": "*",
                    "ops": "*",
                    "request": "*"
                }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

But for whatever reason, this error was not caught.

Is there a way to catch every error, and send a 500 error to the waiting client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the route code?  It sounds like you are calling `reply` inside a call back, or at the end of a promise chain.  When the error happens `reply` doesn't get called.

If you are using promises you might be doing something like this:

```
const myHandler = (req, reply) {
  knex('users')
    .first()
    .where('id', req.params.id)
    .then((user) => reply(formatUser(user))
}
```

If the database connection fails then reply is never called so the server waits forever.  You could modify it to add a catch to the end of the promise chain ie `.catch((e) => reply().code(500)` or you could just return a promise and hapi will turn an rejected promise into a 500.

```
const myHandler = (req, reply) {
  const p = knex('users')
    .first()
    .where('id', req.params.id)
    .then((user) => formatUser(user))

  reply(p);
}
```

I don't know if this meets your request of automatically catching errors, but from Hapi's point of view there was no error, the `reply` was never called.

If you'd like to set a timeout for the route to return a 503 if `reply` is not called in a number of milliseconds you can do that in the route options:

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/api/users/{userId}'',
  config: {
    timeout: {
      server: 10000
    }
  },
  handler: myHandler
});
```

Or set up a timeout on all routes when setting up the connection on the server:

```
server.connection({ port: 80, routes: { timeout: { server: 10000 } } });
```

Setting up a timeout is good practice, but it's still essential that one way or another your handler is guaranteed to call the reply call back.  That way your routes will fail faster.

Comment: This is exactly what we were doing: 
    .then((user) => reply(formatUser(user))

Comment: Then save your promise chain: `const p = dbStuff().then(formatUser)` then `reply(p)` at the end.